# taking json values and search into DOM, is there a better way to do it?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm playing with Facebook json opengraph, taking Facebook likes and comments and adding some widgets on my homepage. Now the problem is that on the homepage there are 25 article nodes, something like that:

```
<article data-href="my_facebook_uri_reference"></article>
```

I wonder it theres something better than this to modify likes counter:

```
$.getJSON('json.js', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function() {

    var $id = ('div[data-href="' + this.id + '"]'),
        $like = $($id),
        $shares = parseInt(this.shares),
        $comments = parseInt(this.comments) || 0;           

        $like.text($shares + $comments);  // here I get fb reactions                            

  });

});
```

if someone wonder, json file is something like that:

```
}
"my_facebook_uri_reference": {
  "id": "my_facebook_uri_reference",
  "shares": 7,
  "comments": 1
 }
}
```

I'm pretty happy with this, just want to know if there's a better way to handle the nodes and don't jump in the DOM pool 25 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a templating solution like mustache. In fact, using templating is a much better solution than manipulating the DOM in loops. It allows you to easily change your html as well without needing to dip into your javascript logic.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively, in Javascript you could create a container node and then append all your article nodes to this container.  Once all the articles nodes a complete, yo can then append the one container to the DOM.